# How to implement nested checkbox list in Sitecore forms field. how do we customize it

Tags: sitecore-forms

[image]

How do i enhance these kind on checkbox in Sitecore forms 9.3

Comment: You can achieve this with javascript, create checkbox fields in Forms and manage those from javascript.

Comment: You should explain in details what you need to achieve. Do you want sub-checkboxes to be automatically checked/unckeched when you click at parent checkbox? Should their data be driven automatically from Sitecore content tree or you need static list only? Which values should be sent to backend?

Comment: Data should be taken from Sitecore tree dynamically and i need to get the data in custom save action sub-checkboxes to be automatically checked/unckeched when you click at parent checkbox-Yes Which values should be sent to backend?-Parent child values should be sent to back end ---
@MarekMusielak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that if you need to do any customizations in `Sitecore Form controls`, then rather than do any modification in OOTB control, you can create your own form control and write the `HTML` or `JS` to fulfill your needs.

For example, I created a `Multiline-Input control` that allows to add multiple text boxes to be filled by the user. Mainly used to add the address in multiline.

So I created my custom control and added the `HTML` and `JS` like below.

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.StringInputViewModel

@{
    var id = Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value);
    var button = Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value) + "_input";
}
<div id="formWrapper">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.LabelCssClassSettings.CssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
    <input type="text" id='@(@id+"_0")' name='@(@id+"_0")' class="@Model.CssClassSettings.CssClass">
    <input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClassSettings.CssClass" type="hidden" value="" @if (Model.MaxLength > 0) { <text> maxlength="@Model.MaxLength" </text> } placeholder="@Model.PlaceholderText" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => m.Value) />

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)

    <input type="button" id="@button" class="input-add" value="Add New" />
</div>

<script>
    var count = 1;
    var addAfterInputId = '@id';
    var inputValue = "";

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery("#@button").click(function () {

            var newInput = '@id' + '_' + count;
            var input = jQuery('<br /><input type="text" id=' + newInput + ' name=' + newInput + ' class="@Model.CssClassSettings.CssClass">');

            jQuery("#" + addAfterInputId).after(input);

            addAfterInputId = '@id' + '_' + count;
            count++;
        })

        jQuery("form").submit(function () {
            jQuery("#formWrapper :text").each(function () {
                if (jQuery.trim($(this).val())) {
                    inputValue += $(this).val() + "|";
                }
            });

            jQuery("#" + "@id").val(inputValue);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Like this, you can extend an existing `Sitecore form control` and write your own `JS` or `HTML` to manage your control.

Here is the link to the blog that I wrote about this new control. You can refer to this and create your own control.

https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2021/11/26/multiline-input-control-multiple-input-text-control/

Hope this will help you to initiate.

Thanks